# How to implement a ByteCountingStreamReader?

Tags: python, stream

How to implement a `ByteCountingStreamReader`?

The `ByteCountingStreamReader` should wrap a file descriptor stream and count the bytes it passed.

A bit like `codecs.StreamReader`, but the content should not be changed, just counted.

Use case: Solve http://bugs.python.org/issue24259

The `tarfile` library does not compare the file size of the TarInfo with the actual bytes read from the tar.

Like this Java class, but for Python: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html

Comment: Isn't the no. of bytes the same as the size of the file? Or do you have a stream/file like object you need to count the length of without consuming it into memory?

Comment: @guettli Why don't you provide an example or use case as a basic for more concrete discussion?

Comment: @JamesMills a file descriptor can have a file which has a size. That's true. But it can be a tcp stream or a stream from a gunzip pipe. There you don't have a file size and you can't use `seek()`.

Comment: @satoru I updated the question and added the use case.

Comment: @guettli It's not clear what you are trying to do exactly and with what? An example would be very helpful!

Comment: @JamesMills I want to count the bytes that have passed a stream. The example can be found in the python bug tracker.

Comment: Yes what kinds of streams? What is a "stream" something that implements the iterator protocol?

Comment: With stream I mean a file like object: https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-file-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small wrapper function that replaces the read method of the (file) stream. It should also work for other types of streams, and a similar wrapper for the write function could be added.

Beware: readline() seems not to use read() internally, so it has to be wrapped, too, if you use it instead of plain vanilla read().

```
def ByteCountingStreamReader(stream):
  fr = stream.read
  stream.count = 0

  def inner(size=-1):
      s = fr(size)
      stream.count += len(s)
      return s

  stream.read=inner
  return stream

# testing it
myStream = open('/etc/hosts', 'r') 
with ByteCountingStreamReader(myStream) as f:
  while True:
      s = f.read(20)
      if s == '':
          break
      print (s, end='')

  print (f.count)
```